# Python requests response - cant unnest the data object

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am querying an API and receiving back a response of type `text`

```
url = "https://tripadvisor1.p.rapidapi.com/reviews/list"

querystring = {"limit":"20","currency":"USD","lang":"en_US","location_id":"2269364"}

headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-host': "xxx",
    'x-rapidapi-key': "xxx"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)
```

[image]

I then want to retrieve a dataframe object. Various online sources suggest this approach:

```
d = json.loads(response.text)
e = json_normalize(d)
```

However, what I get back is this:

[image]

I would like to obtain a dataframe object from the 'data' column. Please advise if I can make this question clearer.

Comment: Try `json_normalize(d['data'])` ?

Comment: [Please, don't post images of text.](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Answer (score 2):

First off `requests` already has a `json()` method on the response object to decode JSON responses. Second, the top level object contains three things: `data`, `paging_results`, and `paging_total_results` which is why you see what you do.

If you want to extract the inner `data` contents, just pull that out before passing it to `normalize`:

```
response = ...
df = json_normalize(response.json()['data'])
```